# Connect to RDS instance with PostgreSQL with AWS Secrets Manager?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, psql, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I have an RDS instance utilizing PostgreSQL in a VPC. This DB uses Secrets Manager for authentication. I created an EC2 within the same VPC and subnet as my RDS instance. I have attached policies to give full access to my EC2 instance.

I have verified I can access Secrets Manager through this EC2 instance by getting a json response of the secretstring and other details.

I use this information to try and access my aurora-postgresql cluster to no avail. connection timed out.

**DB accepts inbound traffic to port 5432.**

Any tips on what to diagnose next?

Comment: "DB accepts inbound traffic to port 5432." from where? What is the full security group rule?

Comment: This question helped me solve my issue. Thank you @MarkB. I had the wrong security group attached to my EC2 instance. For those who run into the same issue, ensure your security group to allow inbound and outbound traffic is attached to your EC2 instance.